# Obtaining a valid IServiceProvider instance in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a proof of concept using ASP.NET MVC and C# in VS 2017 Community to create seed data.

This is my base abstract class:

```
public abstract class SeedBase
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext appDBContext { get; set; }
        public SeedBase()
        {

        }

        public SeedBase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            appDBContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        }
        public abstract void Seed();
    }
```

Then I also created an identity abstract one to allow user seeding:

```
public abstract class IdentitySeeding : SeedBase
    {
        protected RoleStore<IdentityRole> roleStore { get; set; }
        public IdentitySeeding(IServiceProvider serviceProvider ) : base(serviceProvider)
        {
            roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>( appDBContext );
        }

        protected abstract string[] GetRoleNames();

        public void SeedRoles()
        {
            string[] roles = GetRoleNames();
            foreach( string Role in roles)
            {
                if (!appDBContext.Roles.Any<IdentityRole>( r => r.Name == Role ))
                {
                    roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Role));
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Seed()
        {
            SeedRoles();
        }
    }
```

Finally, I created a seeder class that takes an array of seed classes and creates the actual seeding:

```
public class Seeder
    {
        public Seeder()
        {

        }

        public Seeder(SeedBase[] SeedClasses)
        {

        }
    }
```

As you can probably tell, however, I can't find any way to get a IServiceProvider instance. I have googled and come across the IAppBuilder interface here on Stack Overflow, but a deep google hunt hasn't revealed any good leads. Then I expanded my search and found out about a mystical "IServiceCollection" which - in theory - should be in the Microsoft Dependency Injection extensions. I am fairly certain I have installed that correctly via NuGet because it gives me a generic version of IServiceProvider that I use in my seed classes. 
It is quite obvious to me that I am missing something but I am not sure what. 
Leads appreciated.

Comment: Define a class which implements IServiceProvider, create an instance of that class => you have a valid IServiceProvider

Comment: BTW You should read about Dependency Injection and how it works in ASP.NET applications

Comment: I know how DI works in general, but there has to be a default implementation, right? I mean, there is already a default rolestore, how do I allocate it? That's what I am missing.

Comment: Choose one of the many DI container libraries you like. Some have a wrapper class for its container that implements IServiceProvider (some don't and you have to implement it by yourself). Use DI for a loosly coupled design and IServiceProvider will help you to loosly couple your DI container too

Comment: OK, this is not going where I want it to go :) I know this stuff. What I want is to call the same effing thing that ASP.NET MVC does. How do I allocate that? All I want is to use what's already there, I don't want to waste weeks or months figuring out how to add my own. I want what's already there. How do I do that?

Comment: I wonder whether it's not just easier to use the DbSets. Getting the application db context is going to be much easier, right?

Comment: Well I am confused, what you are really asking. EF has already a mechanism for seeding data and you do not need any DI for that

Comment: And for DI: If your class needs an ApplicationDbContext then do not pass IServiceProvider in constructor which will be asked for that, instead pass ApplicationDbContext in constructor and build the class from the DI container.

Comment: EF seed data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3